# Call function in document.ready

Tags: jquery

Can I call function in  document.ready(function(){ })  by using "onclick" event...?

```
      document.ready(function(){
      function MyFunction()
                {
                  alert("Hello");
                }
                });

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:MyFunction()"></a>
```

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot do that becuase the onclick handler uses `eval()` to evaluate the javascript expression and `eval()` expects `MyFunction()` to be a global function and when it is defined inside the `.ready()` handler, it is not a global function so `eval()` does not find it.

You can make MyFunction be a global function by defining it in the ready() handler like this:

```
window.MyFunction = function() {...}
```

But, it would be better to just use jQuery's event handlers and not specify the event handler in the HTML.

```
<a id="myLink" href="#">Click Me</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myLink").click(function() {
        alert("Hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 for it being better to use jQuery's event handlers instead of putting it in the HTML. This is cleaner and much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

The "javascript:" is unnecessary.  And yes, you can.  As long as you define it in a scope that's accessible (in other words, the global scope).

```
function example() { console.log("Called!"); }

$(document).ready(function() { /* code */ example(); /* code */ });

<a href="#" onclick="example();">Example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to keep your code out of the global scope, you can do something like this:

```
var myApp = {

    myFunction: function() {
        alert("Hello");
    }

};


$(document).ready(function() {
    myApp.myFunction();
});
```

However, you will not be able to call any functions defined within an anonymous function because they are both out of scope and inaccessible.

So in short, you cannot call a function from outside of document.ready if that function is defined within the document.ready.